# get rgbdslam map data

Tags: slam, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ROS electric on Ubuntu 11.10..

I want to use kinect for SLAM. In this process I can't get the map generated

using rgbdslam package and I don't know how to obtain the rgb and depth data

generated by the sensor. Just look display ( roslaunch rgbdslam

kinect+rgbdslam.launch )Where is the map, the rgbd data stored and how can I

obtain it?

I am new to this thing.

somebody help me~~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39161/get-rgbdslam-map-data/) by [hahaha](https://answers.ros.org/users/2764/hahaha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-07-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2012-07-19**:
Take care in tagging, you misspelled rgbdslam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the gui that is brought up with that launch file, there is a save option in the file menu. If you want to view the model outside ros, I recommend you save it as a .ply file. It's a more common 3D model. It takes a while to save the data (It's a big file).

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2012-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1